# Show custom view over tab bar in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uialertview

I want to show custom view over tab bar. I have seen that `UIAlertView` shows view over `UITabBar` and user can't interact with tab bar when `alertView` is open. I tried it by showing it over the `keyWindow` by using the code below:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:myViewObject];
```

but user can still change the tabs.

Answer (score 2):

I used to do it with overlayView when I create custom controls that need to block the block whole window and show

```
//self refers to active UIViewController
UIView *overlay =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.window.rootViewController.view.bounds];
overlay.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:.4];
overlay.tag = 1001;
[overlay setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:overlay];
```

you can add a tap gesture to remove overlayView from superview .

Answer (score 1):

try this out:

```
UIView *coverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
coverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
coverView.alpha = .3f;

UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows].lastObject;
[window addSubview:coverView];
```

Comment: Window object does not support orientations, because it is applied on rootviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `tabBarController.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = false` on the tab bar while the custom view is shown.